# Angular calling service mehtod inside of ng-bind-html attribute

Tags: angularjs, service, ng-bind-html

is there a way how to call service method inside of ng-bind-html attribute?
Like:

```
ng-bind-html="flash.getMessage()"
```

Thanks

Comment: if `flash` is service then it should bounded to `$scope.flash = flash; //where flash is dependency instance`

Comment: You can do it the way you posted. What problem do you have?

Comment: Pankaj Parkar: I have $scope.flash = flash;

dfsq: {{flash.getMessage()}} is working, but in the ng-bind-html attribute it is not showing. Have no idea why.

Comment: Is $sanitize available? The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) says that: "_To utilize this functionality, ensure that $sanitize is available, for example, by including ngSanitize in your module's dependencies (not in core Angular). In order to use ngSanitize in your module's dependencies, you need to include "angular-sanitize.js" in your application._"

Comment: Thanks Andrea, that was it!